# AngularJS - How to access to the next item from a ng-repeat in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I'd like to access to the parameters of the next item on screen when clicking on a button.

I use a ng-repeat in my html file:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query" ng-show="isSelected($index)">
    <a href="" ng-click="itemNext()"><img src="xxx.jpg" /></a>
</li>
```

And the index in my Controller with a loop:

```
$scope.itemNext = function () {
    $scope._Index = ($scope._Index < $scope.nbItems - 1) ? ++$scope._Index : 0;
    $scope.functionToCallWithNextItem(nextItem.param1);
};
```

A simple `$scope.items[$scope._Index].param1` instead of `nextItem.param1` wouldn't work as the data is filtered so `$index+1` from `$scope.items` isn't necessarily the good one.

Any idea ?

Comment: are you having any specific issue? what's not working as expected?

Comment: where is `nextItem` declared? where is `_Index` used? there are many missing pieces.

Comment: `nextItem` doesn't exist, I didn't know what to put instead, that's actually what I was looking for... _Index is the current index of the item on screen.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can assign your filtered data to a variable:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (items | filter:query))">
```

Then use `$index + 1` to get the next item:

```
<a ng-click="itemNext(filteredItems[$index + 1])">
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/OdL5rIxtTEHnQCC3g4LS?p=preview

Comment: thanks @tasseKATT, that works fine ! But how can I handle the loop to the first item when reaching the last item that way ?

Comment: (click on `some_item_9` from your plunker example to see what I mean)

Comment: @Surreal, if it works for you, tick the answer accepted

Comment: I found that adding this on top of the itemNext() function may be a solution: `if(item === undefined) item = $scope.filteredItems[0];` what do you think ? Plunker updated: http://plnkr.co/edit/b66BTsVRGIqP9jb2RShc?p=preview

Comment: Depending on where you would prefer to add the logic. Could always use the ternary operator and $last to check if the repeated element is last in the iterator: ng-click="itemNext($last ? filteredItems[0] : filteredItems[$index + 1])"

Comment: ok but is there a way get the index of the next item in the controller that way ? how can I get the index when I have the item itself actually ? Without passing it as a parameter in the function obviously.

Comment: main question is: how to call the `itemNext()` function to init the app if I only have the name of the item. let's say in the plunker example I want to simulate a click on `some_item_7` when launching the app, how would I do ?

Comment: You can use the $filter service to perform the filtering inside the controller instead. Maybe something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/tiBNnDkM5lU3iW2GyNCn?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It's simpy that

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
     current: {{item.value}}
     next: {{ items[$index + 1].value}}
     previous: {{ items[$index - 1].value}}
</div>
```