# get sorted index on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I am using ng-repeat on an array of data where each value has 'type' of either 'chart' or 'table'. On the repeat the values are ordered so that charts appear before tables. I am adding a class for what type each item is and need to add a class indicating what the following item is, such as `class="chart next-chart"` or `class="chart next-table"`.

The issue is the index is reflecting the unsorted data. How do I pull information about the next item in a sorted list?

Here is the code so far:

```
<div class="{{objItem.type}}" ng-class="'next-' + chartData[$index + 1].type" ng-repeat="objItem in chartData | orderBy:'type'">{{objItem.name}}</div>
```

Comment: can't you sort it inside the controller?

Comment: Try: objItem in chartData | orderBy:'type' track by $index

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311232/angularjs-how-to-access-to-the-next-item-from-a-ng-repeat-in-the-controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to deonclem for pointing to a solution:

```
<div class="{{objItem.type}}" ng-class="'next-' + filteredItems[$index + 1].type" ng-repeat="objItem in (filteredItems = (chartData | orderBy:'type'))">{{objItem.name}}</div>
```